# SQL - Return specific part from XML type

Tags: sql, xml

I have looked stackoverflow for XML extraction but none of them helps on this xml format. I've  tried using many different ones from here but none of them return what I need. The problem I think is that it is not in nodes but the XML file is a whole line of NOTE values. I am confused :(

I have a table called XMLTable with 2 columns

```
- ID (int)
- Annotations (xml)
```

I am inner joining the XMLTable with another table based on the ID and I need to select also the date part from the XML field ('Label Date')

```
SELECT s.*, x.Date
FROM Statement s
INNER JOIN XMLTable x
ON s.ID = x.ID
```

Could you please help me to select the Date only from xml table? 
(Using SQL 2012)

XML format:

```
<ANNOTATIONS>
  <NOTE Label="Date">2015-01-13T09:24:58.903</NOTE>
  <NOTE Label="Type">ABC</NOTE>
  <NOTE Label="Status">Done</NOTE>
  <NOTE Label="Unit">KG</NOTE>
  <NOTE Label="GUI">aa11123-zxc6-1111xxxxx</NOTE>
  <NOTE Label="GUIID">10</NOTE>
</ANNOTATIONS>
```

Thank you very much for any advise!

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to read, that we could help you to solve your problem. It would  be very kind of you to accept one of the answers (the check below the vote counter). This shows to the others that this question is solved and it means reputation points for the one you chose. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please don't forget to check one of the answers as accepted, thx!

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
SELECT s.*, x.Annotations.value('(/ANNOTATIONS/NOTE[@Label="Date"])[1]','datetime') AS AnnotationDate
FROM Statement s
INNER JOIN XMLTable x
ON s.ID = x.ID
```

Comment: Probably it was a typo, value should be bound to column rather than to table name.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, Yes, of course! Thx for the catch! I'll vote your's up, even if it is identical with mine now (OK, except for the column name :-)  )

Comment: :) Thanks. I could make it different but would be unnecesserily long then. ie: WITH  xmlData ( id, label, value )
        AS (
             SELECT id, t2.MyNotes.value('@Label', 'varchar(50)'),
                    t2.MyNotes.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
             FROM   [xmlTest] AS [xt]
             CROSS APPLY [data].nodes('/ANNOTATIONS/NOTE') AS t2 ( MyNotes )
           ),
      parsed
        AS (
             SELECT id, CAST(value AS DATETIME) AS MyDate
             FROM   [xmlData]
             WHERE  label = 'Date'
           ) ,..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  s.*,
        x.Annotations.value('(/ANNOTATIONS/NOTE[@Label="Date"])[1]',
                            'datetime') AS MyDate
FROM    [Statement] s
INNER JOIN XMLTable x ON s.ID = x.ID;
```